# generate permutation of a list in python issue

Tags: python

Below is the code I wrote to generate all permutations from a list.

```
def perm(arr):
    if len(arr)==1:
        return (arr)
    if len(arr)==0:
        return ([])
    else:
        result=[]
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            x=arr[i]
            xs=arr[:i]+arr[i+1:]
            for p in perm(xs):
                result.append([x]+p)
    return (result)

perm(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I got error below:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I spent a long time trying to figure out why, but I could not. Can anyone help with why above code give those error? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: do you need this code to work or do you only want to get all permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if len(arr)==1:
    return (arr)
```

A list with only a single value only has one permutation - the list itself. But your function is supposed to return a list of permutations - in other words, a list of lists - so you have to wrap it in another list:

```
if len(arr)==1:
    return [arr]
```

Before the change, the result for single-element inputs wasn't a list of permutations, it was just a list of values:

```
>>> perm([1])
[1]
```

After the change, the result is correct:

```
>>> perm([1])
[[1]]
```

Comment: if I use generator,  it seems that I have to do: ```yield arr```.  I'm still kind of confused.... would you clarify me on that? @Aran-Fey

Comment: @zesla Not without being able to see your code. You can/should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools
a = "123"

b = itertools.combinations(a,2)
for i in b:
    print i
```

your code is fine, just a small fix

```
result.append([x] + [i for i in p])
```

Comment: I'm trying to practice programming instead of using existing tools @shahaf

Answer (score 0):

The code can be cleaner if you just use `str`s, instead of lists:

```
def perm(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        result = ""
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            x = arr[i]
            xs = arr[:i] + arr[i + 1:]
            for p in perm(xs):
                result.append(x + p)
    return result


print perm('abc')
```

> ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']

That solves the bug when appending the subproblem solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with parentheses.

`return (arr)` will return `arr`, not `[arr]`.

`return [arr]` will fix the problem.
Other parentheses in return also do nothing.